# Other alternatives to virtual inheritance?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++11, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

This is a classic example of virtual inheritance in C++ (copied from [cprogramming.com](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html)):

```
class storable
{
public:

    storable(const char*);
    virtual void read();
    virtual void write(); 
    virtual ~storable();

private:

    // some data...      
};

class transmitter : public virtual storable 
{
public:
    void write();
    ...
};

class receiver : public virtual storable
{
public:
    void read();
    ...
};

class radio : public transmitter, public receiver
{
public:
    ...
};
```

I have used this kind of approach before on similar hierarchies, however, I was interested in finding out what other alternatives do we have for this specific example. How could we replace virtual inheritance in this case? Using some form of composition? [Mixins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin)?

Or is virtual inheritance indeed the best approach?

Comment: I'm taking suggestions on how to make it more specific. Have searched the net and didn't find much on this subject. I'm still curious to know more...

Comment: Or, if you guys think it might be better suited to [programmers.stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) ...

Comment: Search the web for "diamond inheritance" and you'll see the root cause and several solutions.

Comment: So what is the point of `storable`?

Comment: @Lol4t0, don't know :P According to the source, this example is from Mr. Bjarne himself, check the link. But regardless of the names, I think the diamond idea is clear, no? Another example could be: `File`, `ReadableFile`, `WriteableFile` and `ReadWriteFile`, the last one having duplicated `File` in its chain.

Comment: Again, `File` is useless if it is an `NonWritableFile` and `NonReadableFile`, doesn't it? Because given `File` you can neither be sure you can _read_ from `File` and _write_ to `File`. I mean I believe diamond problem is always result of bad design.

Comment: In case of File I'd better make `File` that supports _Read_ and _Write_ strategy. Then `WritableFile` just has _actual_ write stratagy and _dummy_ read stratagy and so on.

Comment: I agree with @Lol4t0 that this example seems somewhat contrived.  But it's based on on the C++ standard library, where `iostream` inherits both `istream` and `ostream` which in turn both inherit from `ios`.  (Or at least that's the way it used to be, I haven't done straight C++ for a while.)  IMHO there are certain cases where the "diamond" is (at least arguably) a legitimate solution, and this is one of them.

Comment: Mixins don't necessarily solve the problem.  Let's say you want to avoid the diamond so you plan on having `FileReader` and `FileWriter` mixins.  But in the course of implementing the mixin classes you'd probably find that they shared some functionality (pathname or URI, position, etc.) And you'd probably want to refactor that stuff into a common base class rather than duplicating code.  But at that point you'd be back to virtual inheritance.

Comment: All valid points, thanks for the comments! And yes, the fact that the std streams use virtual inheritance is an indicative that virtual inheritance for such case is the proper approach. However, that might also be one of the reasons why many programmers seem to dislike the standard streams...

Comment: @David, I think the next thing to pop up in that mixin implementation would be the "CRTP".

Answer (score 1):

There was an interesting presentation in the last Going Native conference that I think would apply here.
[Inheritance Is The Base Class of Evil by Sean Parent](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil).